# Install yt-dlp in node:16.3.0-alpine base image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, yt-dlp

This is my Dockerimage:

```
FROM node:16.3.0-alpine

WORKDIR /home/node/app

RUN apk update
RUN apk upgrade
RUN apk add --no-cache ffmpeg
RUN apk add --no-cache python3
RUN apk add --no-cache yt-dlp
```

When I try to build it fails at the yt-dlp step:

```
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: unable to select packages:
  yt-dlp (no such package):
    required by: world[yt-dlp]
The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache yt-dlp' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I don't understand why it can't find the package since it [clearly exist](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=yt-dlp&branch=v3.16&repo=community&arch=&maintainer=) in the community repo, which is enabled by default in the alpine image I'm using.

PD: I need the node base image to be version 16 because the app I'm trying to run (wiki.js in its last stable release) runs in node 16

Comment: Why `node:16.3.0-alpine` ?  Try a more recent image. https://hub.docker.com/_/node

Comment: @GillesQuénot because the app I'm trying to run only runs in node 16 unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the latest Node 16 version `16.20` you can successfully use `yt-dlp`.

Here is a working Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16-alpine
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache yt-dlp
```